# Meaning of Syntax in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, temp-tables

What does this particular statement mean, I came across a stored procedure where this condition is validated multiple number of times.

Can anyone explain this for me please. Well I understand broadly that we are checking if this temporary table exists or not.

I don't get it what do the two dots '..' signify and what is meaning of 'U'

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#tablename', 'U') IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

OBJECT_ID function checks whether that particular table exists in the database or not and U specifies the USER TABLE.

Answer (score 1):

...and the `'TEMPDB..'` prefix means it exists in the tempdb database under your default schema (which is usually `dbo`).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [OBJECT_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) documentation. It returns an identifier for an object in the databases. In this case, it's looking for a user ('U') created temp table with the name #tablename in the default schema (..).

You can also look at the [sys.objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) documentation. Specifically 'type' for the valid 'object_type' values.